# Fixing a TV remote with a low voltage button

Tags: voltage, button, repair, remote-control, remote

I'm trying to fix my TV remote (Panasonic Viera) as one of the buttons has become unresponsive. I've cleaned it with alcohol and noticed the voltage across is just 0.3V rather than 2.7V across the working buttons. On the faulty button, it's 0.3V across the entire pad. Anyone know why the voltage is so low? Is there a fix to this?

Comment: Do you have a circuit diagram?

Comment: @Andyaka I'm afraid not.

Comment: @JohnM. You can get replacement conductive pads for those keyboards, if nothing simpler fixes it.

Comment: Have you considered just buying a new remote control?  There are lots available online.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons on remote controls are often arranged in a matrix (grid of rows and columns) to conserve I/O pins on the microcontroller. The rows are polled while the microcontroller observes the voltage on the columns to determine which, if any, buttons are being pressed. It is likely the button you are trying to measure the voltage of isn't seeing a voltage for very long because it is being polled rather than constantly fed a voltage. However, it's odd that you're able to read a voltage across a different button.

If you've cleaned the board and button with alcohol, my next step would be to apply some graphite from a pencil to the rubber foot of the button and see if that helps. The rubber bits of remote controls can lose their conductivity if worn out.

Comment: Does it seems to be conducting all the time?